# HTML5 Game code with Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to create a tile based 'whack a mole' game in HTML 5. Also at every instance a new mole appears at a given tile an audio prompt needs to given indicating where the mole is(this is so that visually impaired individuals can also play it ). Additionally on hover over each tile its location needs to be said aloud (eg.(3,4)). Now the problem is I am not sure how do I start programming this in HTML5. Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to try panda.js it is a html5 game engine for mobile and desktop
and it has video tutorial
the showcase itself had whack a mole like game
http://www.pandajs.net/showcase/

(full disclosure: I've used pandajs myself)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basics in javascript. You'll need this to do anything in HTML5 canvas:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Then proceed learning about HTML5 canvas:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-tutorials-introduction/